# Visual C# webclient no status code when exception message is The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive

Tags: c#, webclient

I have a windows form application in C# that uses Webclient to download the source code of a website, I am displaying the status code in case of exception. When the Webexception message is

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive

The status code is not shown, rather the program breaks with the error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

My code is like:

```
string source = "";
try
{
  source = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync("URL");
}
catch(WebException er)
{
  textbox1.AppendText("\r\nError: " + er.Message + "Status Code: " + ((HttpWebResponse)er.Response).StatusCode);
}
```

Comment: I tried initialisation `int statuscode = 0; statuscode =(int)((HttpWebResponse)er.Response).StatusCode`

Comment: Have you been using the debugger to find out which object is null?

Comment: er.Response is showing as null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From MSDN on the value of `WebException.Response`:

> If a response is available from the Internet resource, a WebResponse
>   instance that contains the error response from an Internet resource;
>   otherwise, null.

- from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.response(v=vs.110).aspx

It's possible for the `WebException.Response` to be null if there is no response available. You should take that out of your `catch` block and instead just print the exception message. Or, if you want to print the `WebException.Response` if one exists, do a null check.